# Pandaboard ES RevB3: Impossible to run or flash Android

Tags: android, pandaboard

I recently successfuly flashed and used Android on a Pandaboard ES RevB2 following the READ_ME file of device/ti/panda.
However, while trying to get it working Pandaboard ES RevB3, previously flashed SD cards (which worked on the RevB2) won't work (no display), and fastboot doesn't recognize the device after launching usbboot.
I see I should change u-boot sources because the memory timings changed (http://eewiki.net/display/linuxonarm/PandaBoard), but I can't locate any u-boot source in my AOSP folder.

Did anyone had this problem and/or knows how to make it work?

Thank you in advance

Comment: I'm having the same problem on both a RevB3 and a RevA6. I've tried every fastboot-enabled u-boot I can find; nothing works. The only luck I've had so far is with a non-fastboot-enabled u-boot through spl.

Answer (score 0):

Im guessing you are using Ubuntu. See this thread:
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/pandaboard/n5h8wKJ84Ok

Apparently, currently 12.04 Ubuntu is not bootable on Rev 3b boards without manual patching, and these patches are not compatible with earlier boards. You have a choice of trying to use a newer kernel/ubuntu which should get it to boot, but then multiple other things will be broken.